# Speech-to-text: google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403

Tags: python, speech-recognition, gcloud, speech-to-text

I am trying to use Google speech-to-text service, according to https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/index.html
I have created project, uploaded audio to gs: cloud, added permissions, downloaded json file named My First Project-7bb85a480131.json. https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/mybucket?project=my-project

that is my file:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/home/joo/Документы/LocalRepository/robotze/My First Project-7bb85a480131.json"
from google.cloud import speech
client = speech.SpeechClient()
audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(
uri='gs://zaudio/audio.mp3')
config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
language_code='ru-RU',
sample_rate_hertz=44100)
operation = client.long_running_recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
op_result = operation.result()
for result in op_result.results:
    for alternative in result.alternatives:
        print('=' * 20)
        print(alternative.transcript)
        print(alternative.confidence)
```

### Issue: i got

google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to mybucket/audio.mp3.

### Full traceback

```
/home/joo/anaconda3/bin/python /home/joo/Документы/LocalRepository/robotze/speech-to-text-googlecloud.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 565, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/joo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 467, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
    details = "my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to mybucket/audio.mp3."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1565253582.126380437","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:74.125.131.95:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1052,"grpc_message":"my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to mybucket/audio.mp3.","grpc_status":7}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joo/Документы/LocalRepository/robotze/speech-to-text-googlecloud.py", line 46, in <module>
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
  File "/home/joo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/speech_client.py", line 341, in long_running_recognize
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/home/joo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 273, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/home/joo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 182, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/home/joo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to mybucket/audio.mp3.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What i tried: gcloud auth application-default login  - login in browser works, but still 403 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can see on your logs, you are able to authenticate your service account inside your code (you are currently authenticating with: starting-account-*******-239919.iam.gserviceaccount.com), however, that service account doesn't have "storage.objects.get" permission over the object "zaudio/audio.mp3".

So you can either:

A.- Give the proper permissions to that service account (may be the role "storage.objectViewer" inside that bucket would be enough, but you could also set it with the role "storage.admin" so it can have more control over that bucket and others).

B.- Authenticate using other service account that have the proper permissions.

Comment: Hm, accidently i recreated new project and reuploaded files to new bucket and code is finished with 0 code, so permission solved, maybe i missed somth first time. But it doesnot return result, however audio is 7mb only, but that is another question

Comment: Glad to know it was solved, if you encounter future issues (with other errors) you can always create another question. Also, be sure your object exists and use prints in between each step to be sure you are properly creating the objects you are sending on each operation.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the following issue:

```
“google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to mybucket/audio.mp3.”
```

To resolve this issue:

- go to your bucket
- click that three dots, choose “Edit permissions”
- Entity: set “User”
- Name: set your email (in this case, my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com)
- Access: “Reader”.

Save and try again. This should resolve this issue. Regardless whether you have created the bucket, whatnot, you have to do this step to explicitly set permission. Hopefully this is useful.